# Netflix like concurrent user limitation on logging in

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am new to Shopify and exploring options to run a streaming service. I want to build functionality through which I am able to limit the number of users concurrently login through a particular account.
That is if say 4 users are logged in through user A it should not allow 5th user at the same time (Based on plan) as people share their login credentials. Does Shopify provide this functionality or any good recommendation of any such app?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this [app](https://apps.shopify.com/trusted-logins) . This is solving similar problem not sure how they are doing it though .
You can configure this app easily and set your custom banner for 5th user (In your case) or also force log out the first user in case of 5th user attempts to login.